# Hide routes that are only used for subrequests in Silex

Tags: symfony, silex

I've created a route `sitemap` that shows the site's sitemap. This sitemap is included at almost every page using the following Twig construction:

```
{% if app.debug %}
{{ render(path('sitemap')) }}
{% else %}
<esi:include src="{{ path('sitemap') }}" />
{% endif %}
```

So that in debug I'll see the page too. This works perfect. Although, the sitemap is also reachable using `/sitemap`. How can I avoid this? I.e. is there a way that I can make the sitemap route only available for subrequests?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you need to check if the currently handled request is a master or a sub-request. This is correctly set by [render](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/TwigCoreExtension.php#L31), then passed down to [handle](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Application.php#L495), then to the [kernel](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/blob/master/HttpKernel.php#L105). Unfortunately, there's no easy way to get the type from your controller (or a middleware).

The HttpKernel emits the KernelEvents::CONTROLLER event after parsing the request, but before executing the controller. This gets the request type.

If you write an event listener like this, you can still abort:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

$app["dispatcher"]->addListener(KernelEvents::CONTROLLER, function (FilterControllerEvent $event) use ($app) {
    $internals = array("sitemap");
    $route = $event->getRequest()->get("_route");

    if (in_array($route, $internals) && $event->getRequestType() == HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST) {
        return $app->abort(403);
    }
});
```

Comment: Indeed, the security service provider was recently included, haven't thought of that - and am not using it at the moment. Are there ways not using Symfony2's firewall?

Comment: @hvtilborg I've changed my answer to a different solution.

Comment: This will not work, as sub requests will have the same remote address as the main request.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your `security.yml` file will allow you to secure your controller:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/private, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1  }
    - { path: ^/private, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

And then put your controller under a path that starts with `/private`:

```
<route id="whatever" pattern="/private/sitemap">
        <default key="_controller">AcmeDemoBundle:Sitemap:whatever</default>
</route>
```

This is a general way to secure all your sub-requests that will start with `/private`, so that people can not access `/private/sitemap`. Embedding the controller will work as the request will be made by your server ( `127.0.0.1` via the loopback interface).

---

- You can now secure any sub-requests in the same way using `/private` attribute in the beginning of your URLs.
- The order of these elements in your access list matters. I generally put the very secure elements at the top of the list.